# Draw image from pixel data arrays

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, pixel, data-url

If I have an array of pixel data in JavaScript, is there a good way to display it on an HTML page?

- On recent versions of Safari and Firefox, I can make a `<canvas>` element and use `putImageData` to display the pixels, but ideally a solution could work on older versions as well and more importantly, work on Internet Explorer.
- Another solution which seems more tangible could be to encode the pixels into a standard image format and create a `data:` URI with the pixels and set that as the `src` of an `<img>` element. Unfortunately, it seems like most image formats are complex and I'm having a hard time finding a simple one that can do the job (BMP looks like a possibility but does not work on Safari). Also, versions of Internet Explorer before IE 8 don't support `data:` URIs at all.

I doubt any exist, but does anyone know of image libraries for JavaScript that can generate image in a standard format? Is there a way to replicate the functionality of a `data:` URI in IE 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does PNG format work for your targets? If so [PNGlib](http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/) looks pretty good.

Also, [JS JPEG Encoder](http://www.bytestrom.eu/blog/2009/1120a_jpeg_encoder_for_javascript) looks good but it takes as input the returned value of Canvas.getImageData().

Don't know what you can do to support IE 7 though.

Answer (score 3):

Canvas is a good solution, for-cross browser support see [Mark Pilgrim's excellent tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120415182927/http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html). Specifically, the "What about IE?" section and using ExplorerCanvas. You can use and create `data:` URIs in the PNG and JPEG formats with canvas.

Comment: The link has broken and I don't know how to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Raphaël
- http://raphaeljs.com/

While this may be slow, and it is not the intended use of the library, it will work with support for browsers you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not go about it by drawing rectangles; that's too slow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check out fxCanvas http://burzak.com/pro/fxcanvas/

I think they implement even ‘putImageData‘ in IE using Flash.